# RH 7.5 Linux using curl with sftp to pull multiple files ending in a particular file extension

Tags: rhel, curl, ftp, sftp

I am in a Red Hat Linux 7.5 environment. I am trying to write a curl script to pull/receive any file from a folder that ends with a particular file extension.

Previously, I have written a script to push/send using curl with the ftps (**NOT SFTP**) option, login & password, full trace logging and 2>&1 for any other errors. I was able to script that because the filenames were local and able to grep'ed by some script logic.

Basically my curl statement to send is this *(No, those are not real references in the string, I changed those values for privacy.)*:

```
curl --ftp-ssl -k --trace /bedrock/fred/logs/sendpdf.log -T /bedrock/fred/brontosaurussteak.pdf -u fflintstn:H4s$anC#0P ftp://bedrockpoobalodge.com:27Memebers/fredflintstone/pdffiles/ >> /bedrock/fred/logs/transfer.log
```

Where all the reference above is in a script and the references to the paths and whatnot are put into variables in a loop processing hundreds of files every hour on the hour. It looks something like this in the working script:

```
curl $curlFTPC $curlTRCMD\_$trFlCntr\_$cntnt.txt $curlSF/$file $curlAHaD &>> $prcssLgFl
```

It is a different matter altogether when you do not know the filenames you will be pulling/receiving.

I've looked at a lot of examples that loop based on an 'curl eval' like this:

```
for i in $(curl https://someserver.com/alpha/beta/gamma/  | grep pdf | awk -F "=" '{print $2}' | jq '.[].full_path' | awk -F '"' '{printf("https://someserver.com/alpha/beta/gamma/%s\n",$2)}')
```

But I just can't seem to get something like this to work to pull/receive under the same protocol and authentication. I am sure I am missing something obvious.

I'm open to a solution or even alternatives so long as it is script'able in bash and is not using Expect, *can use sftp* AND I can have a full trace and logging of stdin, stdout & stderr.

I'm not open to using 'Expect'.

Comment: IMHO this: `ftp://bedrockpoobalodge.com:27Memebers/fredflintstone/pdffiles/` is not valid URL

Comment: No, those are not real references in the string, I changed those values for privacy.

Comment: try using `wget` instead of `curl` -- it seems to support `mget` / globbing (look at this [page](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/FTP-Options.html) -- it could be as simple as `wget --user=user --password=password ftps://host/path/*.pdf`). I cannot give you an answer because I'm not able to test anything right now.

Comment: @mosvy : Can `wget` be used in a script and can allow logging?

Comment: you seem to confuse `sftp` (ftp-imitating file transfer over ssh) with `ftps` (ftp + ssl, just like https is http + ssl). Your examples are clearly using the latter. If that's really the case, yes, `wget` supports logging (with the `-o` option) and can be used from a script ;-)

Comment: You're right, I am confusing the two. I need more schooling on that. I'm not very experienced in this, so thank you for your patience and assistance };^D>

Comment: @mosvy I tried to update the posting to reflect what I was talking about sftp/ftps.

Comment: Then why have to you changed back ftps -> sftp in the title ;-)?

Comment: @mosvy because I have to use sftp when pulling data in. The other script was made using ftps, yes, but that was for pushing data out. Basically it is a process that reads a config file for a client. This config file has the options necessary  each client for the `curl` command to push data out. But for pulling in, I have to devise a strategy that uses sftp, not ftps. Is that more clear?

Comment: Then you should change back the tags, too. You can use the `sftp(1)` command directly for that, with the `-b` (batch) option (The `get` command from `sftp` supports glob patterns). If you have to use password auth, you'll have to use something like `sshpass` -- see the example  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5386587/10306503). I cannot vouch for it as I don't use `sshpass`, ever -- I'm always using `ssh` with public key auth.

Comment: @mosvy - any chance you could provide an example usage ?

Comment: The link I gave you contains an example usage. Instead of `put your-file-log` you can do `get *.pdf`, or any other command. You have a list of all commands in the manpage.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` for the rescue. `wget` designed for file transfer and logging.

Comment: Can you give an example usage showing how this could help the OP?

Comment: @dudi-boy Using sftp? Can you provide a usage example?